# How to get coupon code in controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost event

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon

I want to do some customisation to cart on submit coupon code from cart, for this I added `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost` event and there I want to get coupon code and check its validation, if it is not valid then I want to apply some custom discount to cart.

But How to get coupon code here and check validity of it in event `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_couponPost` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code');
```

Take a look at `\Mage_Checkout_CartController::couponPostAction` at how Magento natively deals with the coupon codes.

Comment: Hello @nikola99, `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code')` working for getting `coupon_code` but how to check its validity?